# Printing multiple parts of the same line matching a pattern using bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, grep

I am writing a unix command to get lines matching abcd at position 87-90 and for the lines matching this critieria it should get me position 10-15, 124-128,250-265.I tried something like this.

```
grep -h abcd  sample.txt |cut -c 10-15,cut -c 124-128,cut -c 250-260
```

Though this is syntactically wrong I hope it conveys what I am trying to achieve.Could you help me concatenate all the results from the multiple cuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cut -c` accepts a list of characters. As described in the man page, "each list is made up of one range, or many ranges separated by commas."

```
grep -h abcd sample.txt | cut -c 10-15,124-128,250-260
```

Comment: thanks it works.I missed one thing.How to get lines containing the string abcd at position say 50-53